# Reading actual decimal value in Hive

Tags: hive, decimal

While trying to cast hive decimals as string, only the significant value of the decimal is considered in hive. This is leading to md5 (hash value) mis-matches when the data is migrated. I need the actual decimal value (including trailing 0's).

Eg:-
Query - select cast(7.500000 as string)
Result - 7.5

Expected result - 7.500000

Comment: This is working in latest hive 4 alpha2
`select cast(cast("7.50000" as decimal(5,3)) as string) string2decimal2string;`
`+------------------------+
| string2decimal2string  |
+------------------------+
| 7.500                  |
+------------------------+`

Comment: @Raid its because you mentioned `cast (xx  as decimal(5,3)`. If OP is confident that all decimal columns are (5,3), OP can use your code. if not, then its not the coluion.

Comment: @KoushikRoy this was an example to show casting decimal to string does not remove zeros from expected output string. It is not clear from OP's question that this is happening only for different sizes of decimal